# Get input type in Twig to determine the label

Tags: forms, symfony, label, twig

I have this

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form-group">   
        {{ form_label(form) }}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Its used to override the main Twig form fields.

But I need the label to be different depending on the type of form field that is being rendered.

How can I get that here and then call something else instead of `form_label` ?

I essentially want to be able to do this, this is because the label it would appear comes after the input for checkboxes, but I want to reverse this / customise it.

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form-group">   
        {% if(type is checkbox) %}
            // checkbox label here
        {% else %}
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        {% endif %}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the blocks that are used to render a specific form type.

For example, if you want to override the label template of an email input, you should override the email_label block:

```
{% block email_label %}
This is the template used for all email input
{% endblock %}

{% block form_label %}
This is the fallback template for all other input types
{% endblock %}
```

You can check which blocks you can override for a specific form view by looking into `form.vars.block_prefixes`.

For example, for a "personnal_email" field of type "email", it'll contain :

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "form"
  1 => "text"
  2 => "email"
  3 => "_form_personnal_email"
]
```

which mean you can override blocks (starting with the less specific one) `form_(widget|label|error)`, `text_(widget|label|error)`, `email_(widget|label|error)` and `_form_personnal_email_(widget|label|error)` (the last one is usefull to override the rendering of a very specific field).

Does it answer your question?

**UPDATE**

here's what you have to do:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form-group">   
        {{ form_label(form) }}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block checkbox_label %}
    <!-- Your checkbox specific label -->
{% endblock %}
```

You cannot access `type` in the `form_row` block as it's only defined in sub blocks of form_widget (see [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L173-L176) for example)

Comment: Useful  answer, helped me to discover something new. Thanks

Comment: See my edit, I am not sure if this helps. I want to be able to use the type and do as I wish with it.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the checkbox_label block?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what you have to do

Comment: That still doesn't allow me to edit the order? What if I want the label last, after the input? Thanks for your help @Gildas!

Comment: In that case, I guess you would have to override the whole row through the `checkbox_row` block. Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom format:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.your_value, 'Your Title of field', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'} }) }}
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.your_value, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control selectJS'} }) }}
         </div>
 </div>
```

or you can use FormType (if you generate entity, this is file in Form folder), like a:

```
<?php

namespace Ens\YourBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class NoticeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title','text', array(
                'label'=>'Title',
                'label_attr'=>array( 'class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label' ),
                'attr'=>array( 'class'=> 'form-control')
            ))
            ->add('text', 'textarea', array(
                'label'=>'Text',
                'label_attr'=>array( 'class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label' ),
                'attr'=>array( 'class'=> 'form-control')
            ))
            ->add('keep_on_top','checkbox', array(
                'label'=>'Keep on top',
                'required'=>false
            ))
            ->add('start', 'date', array(
                'attr'=>array( 'class'=> 'hidden')
            ))
            ->add('end', 'date', array(
                'attr'=>array( 'class'=> 'hidden')
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ens\YourBundle\Entity\Notice'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'notice';
    }
}
```